# Android implementation of tutorial screen

Tags: android

I'm planning to implement tutorial screen for Android app.
My plan is that tutorial screen looks like:   [image]

There are several screens and you can swipe between than. Every view has custom design. There are dots which represents every screen, and show what page are you watching now. I need good-looking transition with adequate animations.
This screen will be full screen activity.

I have found several Image Galery, but I don't want to slide between images, I need to slide between views.

I do not need exactly code for this. I need instruction in which way this can be done, and what elements I need to use in order to achieve targeted design.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try PaoloRotolo AppIntro on Github: https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro

Comment: Try this: http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use ViewPager in conjunction with Fragments, the instructions are on Android developer's [website](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).

Comment: if you're looking for an all-in-one fast implementation, just find a library such as what @Script Kitty pointed out